# Can't seperate columns from .txt file

Tags: python-2.7

I have a large text file (>10k rows), looking like this:

`"t" \t "cell.id" \t "c" \t "age" \t "cell.volume"
0 \t 1 \t 2 \t 0 \t 1
1 \t 1 \t 2 \t 1 \t 1`

Where the `\t` are tabs separating the values from each other.
I want to use column 1 ("cell.id") and 2 ("c") in a list looking like:

`"cell.id"   "c"
1   2
1   2
...
6000  2`

so I can use them in a loop, where I can relate the `"cell.id"` to its `"c"`, and check whether the `"c"` of one `"cell.id"` is similar to one of another.

Whatever I try, I can't seem to make this work. I have tried using numpy, dataframe, the csv-function and some other things. For some reason

`rawtext = 'location/file.txt'
growth = rawtext.splitlines()`

followed by

`len(growth)`

only gives me the value 1, while i expected a really big number. I'm new to python, and have no clue how to solve this issue.

I also need to be able to crossreference this to another list later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `csv.reader` or `csv.DictReader` and set the delimiter to `\t`:

test.csv

```
"t" "cell.id"   "c" "age"   "cell.volume"
0   1   2   0   1
1   1   2   1   1
```

Then:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        print(line)

#  {'cell.volume': '1', 'age': '0', 't': '0', 'cell.id': '1', 'c': '2'}
#  {'cell.volume': '1', 'age': '1', 't': '1', 'cell.id': '1', 'c': '2'}
```

If using `csv.DictReader` the output as you can see is a list of dictionaries: each line is represented as a dictionary and each key-value pair is the header and its respective value.

You can also use `pandas`. Again the key here is to set `\t` as the delimiter:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter='\t')

print(df)

#        t  cell.id  c  age  cell.volume
#     0  0        1  2    0            1
#     1  1        1  2    1            1
```

**Important** If your file contains literal `\t` it will be parsed by as `'\t'` *literally* and not as tab. You will need to actually press the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

Comment: Thanks, I got the same output as you gave me. Can I also add this dict to a variable by creating an empty list and `.append`, or something? I want to be able to reference this file and reference the `'cell.id'` and `'c'` part.      EDIT: nvm I see now that it already is a variable `reader`. does the last part of the question still stand, tho?

Comment: @MatthijsGroen I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I want to be able to do something along the lines of: if cell.id = 1 and cell.id = 2 do not both have c = 2, give me a warning. I also have to remove duplicates from the cell.id column.

Comment: @MatthijsGroen Then use the `pandas` approach. It will be easier to implement this logic with a dataframe.